# Changing page iOS is causing exception with alertview

Tags: ios

I am getting a strange exception as can be seen below;

[image]

I think this might be because I am navigating to a different page, and then by the time the user has selected the alert view message box button the page has changed and maybe the alert view pointer has gone or something? Please can someone confirm this might be the case? I am changing page in the first of the if else statements using the following line

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The rest of the code can be seen below;

```
- (void) registerAck: (NSNotification *) notification{
    NSLog(@"Detected callback for register");
    NSString *status = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"result"];
    if([status rangeOfString:@"Successful"].location != NSNotFound){
        //succesfully registered

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome"
                                                        message:@"Thank you for registering. Please login using the created details"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


        NSLog(@"%@", status);
    } else if([status rangeOfString:@"User Already"].location != NSNotFound){
        //already registered
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"User Already Registered"
                                                        message:@"Please choose a different username"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"%@", status);
    } else if([status rangeOfString:@"Email Already"].location != NSNotFound){
        //already registered
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Already Registered"
                                                        message:@"Please choose a different email address or use the forgotten password link"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"%@", status);
    } else{
        //failed
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"We are sorry"
                                                        message:@"Registration Failed"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"%@", status);
    }
}

-(void) alert:(UIAlertView *) alert didDismissWithButtonIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
}
```

If this is the case then - what would a potential fix be, I mean, for one instance I want to navigate the user back a page but for other use cases in the if else i want the user to remain on the current page so its not as if i can modify the `didDismissWithButtonIndex` method to change page in there?
Thanks

Comment: You may enable NSZombie to get a may implicit error message. But since the `UIAlertView delegate` is not set, I don't understand how your code should enter the `alert:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method. And it should be `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set delegate to nil in the first alert view. It is trying to call the delegate methods on a view controller that no longer exists when the user taps "Ok". You only have one option for the user to click so you don't need to implement any of the delegate methods for that alert view.

```
    //succesfully registered

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome"
                                                    message:@"Thank you for registering. Please login using the created details"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```